# How to interpret detached backward arrow in SmartGit Git log?

Tags: git, smartgit

I am having Git merge troubles.

Rather than ask a question regarding the problems I'm running into, I would like to ask a question regarding how to interpret the arrows / branch histories when viewing the Git log using the "log" command in SmartGit.

Here are two screenshots of the SmartGit log.

The first is understandable to me, but I include it so that people reading this question see the context of the branches.  This shows the current tip of the branches:

[image: tip of branches]

Here is a screenshot of the Git log, some time previous in the history:

[image]

**I do not understand what is meant by the complex arrows in the above screenshot.**

Here is what I **do** understand:

- *The thin red and blue arrows represent the merge that has not yet been committed.*  I understand this.

Here is what I **do not** understand:

- **What does the red arrow that points down represent?**  Why does it not join directly to the red line beneath it?

I may have other questions, depending on the answer to this first question.  However, this is a sufficient question for me now.

Thanks!

Comment: Is there any kind of filter associated with your Log Window? Did you click on certain branches only in the branch window?

Comment: @VonC I was careful to select all branches to be viewed in the log, to see if this explained the issue.  All branches are selected for view in the above screenshots.

Comment: Is it possible that the commit origin/staging *parent* (the one before origin/staging) isn't visible on this screen, and the red arrow is the SmartGit way to say: go down in order to see that parent?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The lines are there for when the commits are far apart.. (I do not know what the magic number is on the arrow creation).

If it did not have the arrows there would be a very big bar that goes all the way down to the upwards arrow.

For performance reasons, rather than trying to generate this line it simply makes an arrow you can click on that will scroll you to the correct commit. This may not make a lot of sense to you right now, but if you have ever seen the Log for Linux or Git on Github, you will see alot of these. Some of them I have seen with 30 arrows from the same commit.

Comment: That was my conclusion (and comment as well), but do you have any element in the SmartGit documentation to confirm your answer?

Comment: http://smartgit.3668570.n2.nabble.com/Follow-arrows-in-log-display-td7158121.html

Comment: Looks legit. +1 The color convention is confusing though.

Comment: Oh, if its just the colour thing that is confusing people, its just because they have a limited number of colours. I personally think they "recycle" the colours a little too often, but you get used to it.

Comment: Yes - the fact that the two colors (the backwards arrow, and the commit line just below it) happened to have exactly the same color didn't help in terms of understanding.  It's clear now.  Thanks.